# How to get only text from string, ignoring tags

Tags: javascript

Let's say i have this string :

```
<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f525.png" alt="??">This is only<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f525.png" alt="??"> <img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f916.png" alt="??">what i want<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f916.png" alt="??">
```

I need to extract only the part of the text without the *<img* tag. In the example above, this is the resuilt i need :

> ```
> This is only what i want
> ```

Is there a fast / simple way to do this, without having to loop the entire string and manually replacing things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DOM?

```js
const str = `<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f525.png" alt="??">This is only<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f525.png" alt="??"> <img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f916.png" alt="??">what i want<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f916.png" alt="??">`
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = str
console.log(div.textContent)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression:

```
/(?<=\>)([^\<][\s\w]{1,})/gm
```

will do this for you. See below:

```
let str = '<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f525.png" alt="??">This is only<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f525.png" alt="??"> <img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f916.png" alt="??">what i want<img class="emoji emoji-small" src="./img-apple-64/1f916.png" alt="??">'

let match = str.match(/(?<=\>)([^\<][\s\w]{1,})/gm);
```

match is an array containing the values ['This is only', 'what I want']

Comment: [Not recommended to use RexExp on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/295783)